# Powershell throws terminating error on reg import but operation completes successfully

Tags: powershell, registry, remote-registry

Both [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106446/system-io-ioexception-the-operation-completed-successfully-exception) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676660/how-to-run-the-reg-file-using-powershell) looked similar but I couldn't find my solution there. I'm having an issue understanding the difference between the behaviour in reg export versus reg import.

When running reg export inside powershell, it returns "operation completed successfully" but reg import throws a terminating error saying "operation completed successfully". The registry file is correctly imported even though it is thrown as an error. An example:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> reg export HKLM\Software\MySoftware C:\Scripts\MyFile.reg
The operation completed successfully.

PS C:\Windows\System32> reg import C:\Scripts\MyFile.reg
reg : The operation completed successfully.
At line:1 char:1
+ reg import C:\Scripts\MyFile.reg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The operation completed successfully.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

[Microsoft's documentation of the reg import command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import) says that the return codes are 0 for Success and 1 for Failure. Why would Powershell return the success as a regular success message for reg export, but throw it as a terminating error for reg import?

I'm running Powershell as an Admin and the logged in user is a local administrator on the server. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `$out = .{ reg import "\\$CurServer\MySharedPath\RegistryBackup.reg" } 2>$null`

Comment: That ignores any errors, so when I deliberately specify an incorrect path to the file name it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Can't you test `$LASTEXITCODE`  after the regedit call, and then throw your own  exception.

Comment: I updated the article to remove the Invoke-Command issues and only focus on the difference between reg export and reg import. $LASTEXITCODE returns 0, which seems correct if we look in the microsoft article on reg import. The question is why reg export returns it as a regular message while reg import throws it as a terminating error.

Comment: Ooooh, you mean I use the $LASTEXITCODE to create my own exception with a if 0 then this if 1 then that, sorry I didn't read your statement fully! Yes, I was thinking that was one solution :) It doesn't really look nice though, doing a try/catch where I solve things in the catch just because it always throws an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "problem" is, you are using PowerShell in ISE. Try using PowerShell directly. The difference? Two strange things first:

1. `reg export` writes its output on success to `stdout`. `reg import` writes its output on success to `stderr` (I would consider that as "strange").
2. ISE throws an exception, if an external program writes to `stderr`. PowerShell does not do that.

In conclusion, ISE throws an error on an actual success message, because it has been written to `stderr`. You can prevent that, using the `Start-Process` cmdlet:

```
Start-Process reg -ArgumentList "import C:\Scripts\MyFile.reg"
```

Because `stdout` and `stderr` of the external program are then not forwarded to your terminal. Instead, you can access them through the parameters `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`, if needed.

If you want to evaluate the exit code, you can do it like this:

```
$process = Start-Process reg -ArgumentList "import C:\Scripts\MyFile.reg" -PassThru -Wait
$process.ExitCode
```

Comment: Just in case there is a space in the registry file path, it makes sense to escape it like (replace BACKTICK with the actual backtick character): $process = Start-Process reg -ArgumentList "import BACKTICK"C:\My Scripts\My File.regBACKTICK"" -PassThru -Wait