# C# UWP - cannot connect to the serial port

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, windows-community-toolkit, virtual-serial-port

I'm working on UWP app and need to read data from a serial port and display them on the graph.

**I'm getting 3 random exception messages :**

> ***Message 1 :*** 
>   `"The operation completed successfully"`
>
> ***Message 2 :***
>   `"An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist"`
>
> ***Message 3 :*** 
>   `"The requested lookup key was not found in any active activation
>    context"`

I don't have a live connection, but I installed a simulator. When I'm trying to establish a connection from the console app it works fine.

**Here is my code, which is really simple:**

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate);
_serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;
try
{
    _serialPort.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

From the `_serialPort_DataReceived` method I want to update the graph.

I know that there is some limitation with the serial port on UWP, but I can't find an appropriate solution.

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of the answers are a solution to my problem.

Comment: How is _"The operation completed successfully"_ an exception message? What type of exception is that? Where is it thrown?

Comment: @Fildor yes, believe me, or not :D It's the "IOException".

Comment: ... odd. And it is from that very catch block in your snippet?

Comment: @Fildor yes, right.

Comment: I don't know how much UWP is at play here but usually my next question would be "are you sure, you safely _**close**_ the port, when your app exits/crashes?"

Comment: I would say I'm good because the same code works fine in the console app.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106712/982149 It's a completely different environment, but I think the cause could be in the same "area" ...

Comment: [This](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/how-to-access-virtual-com-port-from-uwp-app/ba-p/720864) may also be interesting for you?

Comment: The creation of your event handler looks weird.  Maybe thats the correct syntax for UWP but usually there is a `new` modifier.  Something like `_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);`

Comment: @Baddack Newer C# syntax allow omit evenhandler. You may just `eventfired += AMethodNameMatchingSignatureHere;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on UWP app and the case is to read data from a serial port and show them on the graph.

In UWP we use [`Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.serialcommunication.aspx) namespace to access serial port. For using above namespace we need add the following capability.

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

For the detail steps, please refer this [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess) .

Comment: When I run the code sample access is blocked by the system but I never get any prompt to allow access to the serial port.  Is there a windows setting somewhere that can be adjusted?